# Does anyone know of a python based web ui for snmp monitoring?

Tags: python, django, pylons, snmp, turbogears

Comparable to cacti or mrtg.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.zenoss.com/

This is a lot more than just SNMP but it is based on Python.

Answer (score 0):

or you can start building your own solution (like me), you will be surprised how much can you do with few lines of code using for instance cherryp for web server, pysnmp, and python rrd module.

Comment: I am not the expert in python but would love to try your project if it is available